# Windows Boot Failure Info

Tags: windows, boot

I'm curious to know where on disk or on the file system that Windows or WinRE stores the information that indicates the number of startup failures that occur. I've read from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference) that if the number of boot failures is greater than two, then WinRE will startup.

Most of my search queries will lead me to troubleshooting tips or information on partition tables. I tried referencing Windows Internals (6th edition), but the boot process section is in part 2 and I only have part 1.

I can only guess that it's either:

- on one of the file systems
- it's on an undocumented data structure outside of a file system
- it's somewhere on the registry, which is on the main file system

But I would like to know where specifically the info (such as the number of boot failures) is stored.

Comment: It really depends at what specific point in the boot process if fails, i may not record it anywhere. Most likely on the boot partition.

Comment: @Moab in the link I gave, it mentions that WinRE will startup on two consecutive failed attempts at starting Windows. Wherever that info is checked is what I'm interested in. The boot partition is really large and so that doesn't really narrow it down. I was hoping for either a file path or an offset within the partition, or something like that.